# How to get a text list of files names in a folder in windows

Tags: windows-7, file-extension

I have a folder that has different file formats, is there a way to get all the files names and their extensions  at once instead of copying and pasting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a command prompt window, CD into the directory in question and then type

```
dir /b > c:\<folder of your choice>\files.txt
```

That will dump the directory listing to a file instead of showing it on the screen.

The /b lists only the file names and none of the date/time stamps, sizes, and other junk you're not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Explorer you can set the View to Details.
But to see the file extensions you need to make a a change to some settings.
If your using Windows 8 > open File Explorer and click on View and then tick File extensions.
If your using Windows 7 > open Windows Explorer > View > Folder Options > View and tic show file extensions.

Then when in the Details view showing all the columns, tick in the Name heading and the files will be sorted according to name.
If you want to print this, use the Dos command as stated in the previous answer.